# how to update a favicon, vimeo style

Tags: javascript, html, css, vimeo, favicon

Vimeo has this nice favicon that changes while uploading a video, it shows the amount of uploaded content in a pie chart style favicon. Can someone point me in the right direction of how to create such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `<link>` to the favicon through normal DOM methods.

See [a live example](http://jsbin.com/egaqor/1):

```
<link rel=icon href="http://www.bluejag.co.uk/favicon.ico">
<!-- ... -->
<script>
function changeFav() {
  document.querySelector('link[rel=icon]').href = "http://www.solaripedia.com/favicon.ico";
}
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', changeFav);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, check [here](https://github.com/Dlom/favicon.js?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email) and [demo](http://dlom.github.com/favicon.js/#) preview.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)